# Contribution page not sending receipt for Paypal payment

Tags: contributions, contribution-page

I activated a contribution page and the PayPal Payflow Pro Integration extension.
This is the log of the error

> 2023-12-05 11:49:44+0100  [error]
> CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Confirm::completeTransaction
> CRM_Core_Exception: DB Error: no such field

in the front end page appear the message failed to update contribution in database

Which is the lost field?

This installation is CiviCRM ver. 5.67.3 on WP

Thank you in advance for the assistance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to enable "Display Backtrace" in "Settings - Debugging and Error Handling" - normally, the exact name of a missing DB field name could be found there. Or in apache/php error logs, depending on how your server has been configured.